# Proving the relationship between monotonicity and derivatives

Tags: functions

> Let $a\in  \mathbb R$. Prove using mean value theorem that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions with $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for every $x$ in some interval containing $a$ and if $f(a) = g(a)$, then $f(x)\leq  g(x)$ for every $x$ in the interval such that $x\geq a$.

For every $f'(x_n)$ and $g'(x_n)$ defined on an interval $[a,x]$, there exists $a,x$ such that 
$$f'(x_n)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ 
$$g'(x_n)=\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$$

After this and a little algebra, we can prove the statement.

However, the above expression is where I am confused. Are they correct? I know they are derived from mean value theorem but it seems the application is incorrect.

The reason I thin the application is incorrect is that I assumed that endpoint of the slope for both the derivatives are same, whereas Mean value theorem doesn't guarantee that.

Can somebody clear the confusion?

Comment: Is not $(g-f)'\ge 0?$ Doesn't this imply that $g-f$ is increasing?

Comment: Yes. But I have to prove and that well as using the mean value theorem. How should I do that?

Comment: Just apply the mean value theorem to $g-f$ on the interval $[a,x].$ You have that $$(g-f)(x)=(g-f)(x)-(g-f)(a)=(g-f)'(c)(x-a)\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = g(x)-f(x)$. Then $\phi'(x) \ge 0$ on the interval.

You have $\phi(a) = 0$.

The mean value theorem shows that for $x \ge a$ we have some $\xi \in [a,x]$ such that $\phi(x) = \phi(a) + \phi'(\xi) (x-a) \ge \phi(a) = 0$
since $\phi'(x) \ge 0$. Hence $g(x) \ge f(x)$.

(Note that similar reasoning shows that for $x \le a$ in the interval that $g(x) \le f(x)$, as you might expect from a picture.)